# Load CustomView and its logic at Runtime

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I'm creating a custom component for an Android App (exactly a volume fader for an audio mixer). It works fine.

What I want is to load several instances of this component at Run-Time.
I tried with this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mixerContainer) //This layout
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
  LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View v = l.inflate(R.Layout.MyVolumeFader, null);
  layout.add(v);
}
```

This adds the view correctly, but doesn't attach all the logic of my component (that is contained in MyVolumeFader class).

How can I solve this problem?

--

The code looks like:

**MyVolumeFader.java**

```
public class MyVolumeFader extends RelativeLayout{
 [...]

 private VerticalSeekBar volumeBar;

 [...]

 ->volumeBar handling<-
}
```

**MyVolumeFader.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout...
Some TextViews, Buttons and a VerticalSeekBar are here...
```

Thank you.

Comment: SOLVED.
The right way is:
    `LinearLayout l =      (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
    MyVolumeFader f = new MyVolumeFader(this, null);
    l.addView(f);`

Remember to use "this" when calling CustomView constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using windowmanager and its' addview method to solve your provlem like this.

```
mWindowManager.addView(new ChartTools(this, a, list, "业务统计").getChart(),
        ParamTools.getChartParams());
```